# How do I get a realtime database reference for an image in storage when uploading on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm able to upload an image to Firebase Storage on desktop and mobile browsers. But the mobile browser will not save the reference in the realtime database. It does on the desktop browser. Is there special code that must be referenced for mobile browsers?

Here's the JS code (it's a WIP):

```
$(fileButton).on('change', function(e) {

  // Get file
  var file = e.target.files[0];

  // Create a storage reference
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(file.name);

  // Upload file to storage bucket
  var uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);

  // Set uploaded file's image URL to real time database
  uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {

    var postKey = firebase.database().ref('posts/').push().key;
    var imageURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
    var updates = {};
    var postData = {
      url: imageURL
    }

    updates['posts/' + postKey] = postData;
    firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

  }, function(err) {
    // if error
    // $('.add-image-error').removeClass('hide');
    console.log('There was a problem uploading the file: ' + err);

  }, function() {
    // if complete, reload the page
    location.reload();
    console.log('File successfully uploaded image and reference');

  });
});
```

Comment: Your code shall work on desktop/laptop and mobile browsers... I do something similar in one of my app and there is no difference at all.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?